# Deploying Sp Solution

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

```
Add Solution - stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Kingen.wsp" 

Deploy Solution-stsadm -o deploysolution -name Kingen.wsp  -url http//xxxx -local  -force -allowGacDeployment
```

Site Collection Administration > Site collection features > Active!

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this page Cannot be displayed or
>   imported. The type is not registered as safe Need to add in Web.Config
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at XX could not
>   be found

How do i solve this i have used powershell to add and deploy my wsp but it says:

> The Web application at http:/XXX could not be found. Verify that you
>   have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing
>   content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL
>   mapping to the intended application

how do i solve it, i am using my friends wsp package that has another url in my site and has another url

Comment: i dont know if you put it in as an example or not but http:/XXX is not what you put in as the url for the webapplication is it?

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty straight forward, it can't find your web application. Go into Central Admin > System Settings > Configure alternate access mappings, and make sure the URL you're using is listed against the correct web application. It's not case sensitive, but it has to match exactly, http||https and and unique ports.

If you are entering it exactly correct, there's a bigger issue obviously. Check the ULS logs for additional info.

HTH